# xcode 5 in storyboard impossible to connect view controller with .h and .m

Tags: xcode, class, storyboard, viewcontroller

I have the Problem that i can`t connect my view controller with a objective-c class.

I have searched if someone has the some problems but i did not find anyone and no thread had a solution for my Problem.

I know how to set the connection with the .h and .m file but when i create a new objective-c class this class is not listed under the classes so i can not connect my view with it in the storyboard. i create the class with xib unchecked so i do not know where the mistake could be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the UIViewController you're creating is of the same class as your class in the code first. Third tab on the right pane in the Interface builder, while the ViewController is selected in the items list.

Answer (score 0):

The only way for me to solve it was to create a new Project, and then everything in this new project worked.